# int from object returns 0 when i access it directly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to retrieve a value of an object however it keep returning 0 when i try an access the `major`, `minor` or `UUID`. However when i just `print` the `beacon.beacon` it returns the correct value. Here is my code:

```
for beacon in allContent {

    print(beacon.beacon!)

}
```

**Returns**

```
Beacon {
    id = 1;
    name = Beacon 1;
    major = 10221;
    minor = 19561;
    UUID = FDA53493-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07646825;
}
```

**retrieve minor**

```
for beacon in allContent {
    print(beacon.beacon!.minor)
}
```

**Returns**

```
0
```

Comment: Would be nice if people could use the dev docs before asking questions. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013054-CH1-SW10

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker this is not a kindergarten